# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Account: bad field names on insert/update call: AccountId

Tags: lightning-aura-components

when I am trying to update contact object field(HiMatchKey__c) with AccountId(account is lookup in contact object) when it is person account it is giving error.Can someone please reply to this.

Answer (score 4):

Many contact fields are moved to the Account object when you enable Person Accounts even though the Contact Object and record will still exist. With a Person Account, the Account Object record will be primary. See the following Help Page for a list of [Person Account Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_fields.htm&type=5).

Comment: I don't know why but for some fields are updating in contact some of them not updating

Comment: It will depend on whether the field is locked to the account record. If it's locked, it's not going to update.

Comment: what do you mean by locked?

Comment: When you update a record, all related records are temporarily locked. If the Account Record is locked by the database, you won't be able to update the Contact Record. More importantly, in this particular situation, many of the Contact Fields are essentially `moved` to the Account Record which becomes the "source of truth". Many fields on the contact record need to be updated from the Account Record and not the other way around when Person Accounts are enabled.